# angular material mat-accordion on click event top scroll in not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

Angular Material -  while click the expansion panel header will call the onExpand function in that time window scroll  to top (or) change the position  not working

```js
onExpand(){
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

```html
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel class="Alert" [expanded]="false" #Completed>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header (click)="Completed.expanded?onExpand():onCollapse()">
      <mat-panel-title>
        <span>
                    <span *ngIf="!Completed.expanded"><img id="Alrtimg" src="assets/img/app/completed_expand.png"></span>
        <span *ngIf="Completed.expanded"><img id="Alrtimg" src="assets/img/app/completed_collapse.png"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="AltMsgtxt">Completed</span>
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <mat-card *ngFor="let alrt of alerts" style="display: inline-block;border:0.6px solid #80808063;">

      <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
        <div fxFlex.gt-sm="100" fxFlex.gt-xs="100" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="100">
          <p class="nudge_title">{{alrt.nudge_entity_name}}</p>
          <p class="nudge_amount">{{alrt.nudge_amount | currency:"INR":'symbol':'1.0-0'}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" style="padding: 0px 0px 18px 0px;">
        <div fxFlex.gt-sm="100" fxFlex.gt-xs="100" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="100">
          <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" value="40"></mat-progress-bar>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
        <div fxFlex.gt-sm="100" fxFlex.gt-xs="100" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="100">
          <p class="AlertDescr">{{alrt.nudge_msg}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-card>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to scroll to the top of the page after you clicked a `mat-expansion-panel` header, then I suggest you use `afterExpand` as described in the Angular Material documentation:

> **@Output() afterExpand: EventEmitter**
>
> An event emitted after the body's expansion animation happens.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-odrwfn?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) is a quick stackblitz I threw together that shows it in action. Just scroll a bit down and click on a expansion panel header, it will open the panel and immediately scroll to the top of the page.

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let i of largeArray" (afterExpand)="scrollToTop()">
  <!-- more HTML -->
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
scrollToTop() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```